# React multi carousel center mode broken, when adjusting width

Tags: reactjs, react-multi-carousel

With center mode on if the width is adjusted
(img width, and item width in styles.css)

The carousel does not scroll the correct amount and the main item is off center.  This seems like it should be solved by additionalTransfrom, but sadly not..

Here is a codesandbbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-grass-m5uz6f?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=600&resolutionHeight=1024

I have also seen this thread, which describes the same problem

https://github.com/YIZHUANG/react-multi-carousel/issues/272